# How do I call JSON data stored as a variable in a different component?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, variables, axios

I am currently drawing JSON data from my api using axios, and I am mapping this data and storing it as a variable. I want to be able to call these variables in my react components, but I can't seem to figure out the best way.

**Getting the JSON data and storing as a variable**

```
function ProfileOne(){
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get("api/profiles/")
          .then(res =>{
              console.log(res)
              setProfiles(res.data)
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
          })
  }, [])
  return (
                  profiles.map(profile => {
                    const { name } = profile;
                    })
            <div>
                <h2><b>{profile.name}</b></h2>
            </div>

  )
}
```

And I want to be able to call something like profile.major in a react component, but the way I am currently trying to do it does not work. Please let me know the correct way to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What means "it does not work" ? what do you get?

Comment: `profile.name` is outside the map, should it be inside the loop?

Comment: When I say it does not work, the react dev tools error shows that profile is not defined @Sowam

Comment: inside the useEffect? @ksankar

Comment: This way, so the your are referring profile where it's defined. In the loop.
`return profiles.map(profile => (<div> <h2><b>{profile.name}</b></h2></div>);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to pass data from component to component you may have to restructure your application or implement a state management library such as redux. Personally I would move your API call to a parent component and then pass the data as props to child components. Something like the following for the parent component:

```
function ParentComponent() {

const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("api/profiles/")
      .then(res =>{
          console.log(res)
          setProfiles(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
      })
   }, [])

return (
    <>
      <ProfileOne profiles={profiles} />
      <OtherComponent profiles={profiles} />
    </>
    );
}
```

And in the child component:

```
function ProfileOne(props){

    return props.profiles.map(profile => (
                   <div>
                       <h2><b>{profile.name}</b></h2>
                   </div>
               )
}
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for! Great answer. Thank you greatly, Josh.